# How do I add expires header to images in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have several images in a bucket on s3. I want to add expires headers so I can improve my yslow score for my site. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have the [awscli tools](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) installed and working. You can move the files around to add the expires headers.

```
aws s3 mv s3://somefile.jpg s3://temp.jpg --expires 2100-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

then just move it back to get the original name